# Adding a setting to category configuration

Tags: catalog, configuration, magento-1.6, xml

I want to add a few admin settings to the Catalog/Manage Categories screen, I've grepped various directories but most of the site is accessed by FTP, where is the XML file that controls the options on this screen?

Comment: For future reference, if you're looking for specific core files, you can search this Github mirror: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tab under the category section of the admin normally relates to a attribute group. So if you have a custom attribute that you want to show up you should be able to add this to the correct group via an install script.

Here is the basics for a set-up script:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

//Add group to entity & all attribute sets
$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_category',
    'attribute_code',
    array(
        'label' => 'Your New attribute',
        'group' => 'Group name here'
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

The groups by default are `General Information`, `Display Settings` and `Custom Design`.

The database tables that these are stored in are:

```
eav_attribute_group - all the groups
eav_attribute_set - all the attribute sets (each group needs a set)
eav_entity_type - this is the entity in your case category (default I think the id is 9)
eav_attribute - the attribute itself
```